# What is the reason/background that the <script> tag is not part of the Same origin Policy

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, script-tag

The last months I read a lot about the Same Origin Policy of browsers and Cross Domain Requests.

All the time I am wondering, for what reasons the `<script>` tag is not part of it? 
I found the question to be asked several times, also here on stackoverflow, but all replies didn't answer why it isn't part of it.

Is this due to historical reasons or what is the background behind this idea?

I hope somebody can help me with this question.

Comment: How do you assert that the `<script>` tag is not part of the SOP? An example, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry I didn't express myself good enough, my english isn't the best. I meant, that the scripts within the <script> can be loaded cross domain and are not restricted by the SOP

Comment: @deceze: It's plain to see on any website that, say, loads jQuery from Google. Like _this one_.

Comment: @Lightness I know what *cross-site-script-inclusion* is, I'm asking the OP to clarify why he thinks scripts are exempt from the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @deceze I think scripts are exempt from the policy, because cross-site-script-inclusion is possible as you just stated.

Comment: Just like external image or CSS resources can be included. Maybe you're misunderstanding what the Same Origin Policy covers.

Comment: @deceze I think he understands what it covers, he's asking *why* it doesn't cover external scripts.

Comment: Yes i know what it covers and what it doesn't cover, but I am interested in the reasons and intentions behind it

Comment: Honestly, my guess is that browsers did things in the very early days before the repercussions of the same-origin policy were fully understood. At a certain point this behavior became so wide-spread it would be impossible to revert or alter.

Comment: @monsur also for me it seems like the most logic explanation, but I'd like to know it for sure ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can we chat, I have some doubts regarding this.

Comment: @deceze SOP main purpose or sole purpose is to not let other origin javascript read the responses, request can always be made, but we cannot read the response. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know they reasons that it was decided that foreign `<script>` didn't need to be blocked, but there are many benefits of that decision.

- Not all scripts have to be hosted on your own site, and, as a corollary,
- scripts can be hosted by content delivery networks that can deliver them faster and allow the client to use cached versions of popular scripts.
- Foreign scripts allow us to have cross-domain AJAX requests via JSONP.

Also, `script` tags historically predate the Same Origin Policy, so it would make sense that scripts could reference files not necessarily hosted by the same site, to be consistent with how the `a`, `img`, `embed`, `frame` and other tags also did.

Comment: I did a little bit more research and found out, that the `<script>` tag doesn't predate the SOP. SOP was introduced with Netscape 2.0, which was released in March 1997: http://sillydog.org/netscape/verinfo.php and the `<script>` tag one year later in January 1997, with the release of HTML 3.2 http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html#script , http://www.the-pope.com/lostHTML.htm#ht0a

Comment: It should be noted that with HTTP2 the use of CDNs should be carefully considered as it may mean extra DNS lookups and certainly means extra connections (HTTP2 makes only one connection to the server usually).

Comment: Script is blocked for the most mime-types. Not even "plain/text" is allowed to read externally. Script can hold accessible static data only if src is not used. If src is used the code can not be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly part of the reason is that the `<script>` tag is much older than the same origin policy, so preventing its use would break a lot of web pages.

I believe the other reason is that the same original policy works to prevent information from being accessed by a different origin than it was created in. The script tag doesn't permit information to be sent to its origin, or at least, no more information than any other GET request such as `<style>` or `<img>` would.

Comment: But the information that also any other GET request such as  `<style>` or `<img>` could send can be pretty harmful? In this answer it is stated that "Any <script> you include in the page has complete access to alter the user's interaction with the site due to the Same Origin Policy"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800253/google-analytics-can-it-collect-form-data

Comment: @Boka A GET request *should not* be harmful. GET requests should not alter any state. And if included scripts could not interact with the current page, they'd be pretty useless. They're secure insofar as *you* have to include them in your site, so it's up to you whether you trust the scripts you include.

Answer (score -2):

Though there are likely ways around it, `script` tag `src` parameters are generally fixed values set in your static HTML. Both historically and even now in terms of security risks, there's not much concern over cross-domain script requests in this fashion. On the other hand, there is certainly a large benefit in allowing it — CDNs for script downloads, jQuery hosted on the cloud, etc. There's also backward-compatibility to consider.

This is not quite as true for AJAX requests, where the script URL may (and often does) come from user input or other *dynamic* state. On average, the barrier to entry for *breaking* this is much lower than for breaking a `script` tag, where "breaking" = "causing a security breach".

- Source: guessing